# How to use bin2h?

Tags: c

I'm trying to use [bin2h](http://www.deadnode.org/sw/bin2h/) to convert a font file (font.ttf) into a C file but it won't work.

Can someone please tell me the syntax to save the output to a text file?

I've been trying to figure this out but nothing is working, and it's driving me insane. I'm really frustrated because I know the tool is working (I got it to work like a year ago) but I can't remember how I used it.

The example syntax on that site doesn't really help...

Please

Thanks to Lightness Races in Orbit's comment below I finally got the syntax right!

bin2h -cz font < font.ttf > output.h

That's working, thanks

Comment: Please show the code you've written so far.

Comment: "it won't work" is not a particularly professional description of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking at the usage example on the website and not realising that it is a program that you execute from shell? It is not a line of C code.

So if you want to use this from a C program, you will need to execute it through a function like `system` or `exec`. However, since its output is a line of C code, you'd be better off running it *from within your build script* to create a C script, that you'd then link in to the rest of your program.

---

### Example (in C++ as my C is rusty — port to C as required):

#### Source code for main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "eula.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::string(eula, eula_size) << std::endl;
}
```

#### Build commands

```
$ bin2h -cz eula < eula.txt > eula.h
$ g++ main.cpp -o myProgram
```

#### Execution command

```
$ ./myProgram
```

Comment: @AurelleDenby: Yes the trick is to "redirect" STDOUT to a file so you can use the output from some other process (in this case, that other process it the C++ compiler).

Answer (score 1):

I would just write my own.

Here's the algorithm:
Open the source code file as text output.
Open the font file as binary input.
Write the array declaration to the output file, something like:

```
static const unsigned char font[] = 
{
```

While the font file is not empty do:
   Read unsigned char from font file, using binary read methods.
   Output the unsigned char, in text format, to the source file.
   end-while

Write the ending brace and semicolon to the source file.