# import file as variable in compilation(CPP)

Tags: c++

I have a CPP file which depends on having a vary large string being declared at the start of the file. I would like to be able to import this string from a text file, and include as a variable during compilation. Please could a shell script and relevant C/++ code be provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare this string in a header file and include this file.

Comment: How would I do that? Please could you provide an example.

Comment: I guess your string looks like:  
`const char *my_string = "Here comes some very long text"  
                            "over multiple lines"  
                            "and a lot more of lines";`  
You can now copy the whole string with its declaration into a separate header file and include this file. But you can only include this header file once in you whole project.   
The proper way would be to copy the string into a cpp file, compile it and link later against it. In a separate header file, you only declare this string as `extern const char *my_string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without external help.

There're plenty of so-called "binary to header" scripts and programs out there. As an example, https://github.com/dparnell/bin2h (just a top hit from a search engine).

**EDIT:** Also, take a look at [How to use bin2h?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064573/how-to-use-bin2h).